# Can't Setup MySQL Trigger To INSERT Into Second Table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables which I use to store call details in.  One table (Call_Detail) stores the header details against each call that gets entered, the second (Call_History) stores every comment against the call.  So a single call will only appear ONCE in the Call_Detail table, but may appear multiple times in the Call_History table.

I currently run a Query to return the latest comment against a group of calls.  So, I return the header details out of Call_Detail and then cross reference against the Call_History to find the 'newest' comment (thanks to some outside help).  However, this Query can be quite time consuming when running against a large number of calls.

Therefore, I'm thinking to optimize my Query, I want to setup a trigger that records these details.
I am wanting to catch any INSERT command into the Call_History table and record the comment and date/time into the Call_Detail table against the relevant call ID.

So far I have the following but it doesn't like my syntax for some reason:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Last_Call_Update
AFTER INSERT ON call_history
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE call_detail
SET last_updated = NEW.updated_at, last_commment = NEW.body
WHERE id = NEW.ticket_id
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Error message should show you exact position of the error.

Comment: Ah yeah - MySQL Workbench was truncating the error message...  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add semicolon after UPDATE statement

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Last_Call_Update
AFTER INSERT ON call_history
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE call_detail
    SET last_updated = NEW.updated_at, last_commment = NEW.body
    WHERE id = NEW.ticket_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ....Wow, it took me longer to write this thread than it did for you to correct my issue!  :)  Cheers Naktibalda!  Much appreciated.